# Расшифровка пароля

Tags: java, шифрование, aes

В общем появилась у меня проблема с расшифровкой пароля. Есть два метода:

метод который шифрует пароль

```
    private byte[] encrypt(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("dfgkirvbn25685la".getBytes(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
}
```

и метод который расшифровывает пароль

```
    private String decrypt(PersonEntity pe) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("dfgkirvbn25685la".getBytes(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    String s = "";
    byte[] bites = cipher.doFinal(pe.getPassword());
    for (byte b : bites) {
        s += (char) b;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Так вот, когда я ввожу пароль в окошке логина, метод заканчивает свою работу на строке `byte[] bites = cipher.doFinal(pe.getPassword());`
и дальше ничего почему-то не происходит. Пароль я получаю из сущности, в которой у меня хранится столбец из байтов

`private byte[] password;`

Вот так хранится пароль в бд [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я как-то не правильно храню эти пароли или расшифровку не правильно делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Замените:

```
byte[] bites = cipher.doFinal(pe.getPassword());
for (byte b : bites) {
    s += (char) b;
}
return s;
```

на

```
return new String(cipher.doFinal(pe.getPassword()));
```